# The used table type does not support BLOB/TEXT columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I am attempting to create a temp table in my stored procedure that obtains a column of data from another table that is text.   But I am getting the

> used table type does not support BLOB/TEXT columns

message.  How can I get around this?   This is my code, `2015Consumer_stage` is the table containing the text column.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `uspLoadStateTables`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE state varchar(2);
    DECLARE rowcount int;

    create temporary table statelist(TheState varchar(2)) engine=memory SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(ST) FROM `2015consumer_stage`;

select count(*) into rowcount from statelist;
select TheState into state from statelist;
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL does not support `TEXT` or `BLOB` for MEMORY / HEAP tables. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/memory-storage-engine.html). `VARCHAR()` is supported but you should try using a `CHAR()` instead. MySQL will store it as fixed-length anyway.