# MySql - doesn't support BLOB/TEXT columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

```
create temporary table if not exists tmp engine=memory 
SELECT id, CONCAT(TRIM(lastName),TRIM(firstName),TRIM(zip)) AS identify
FROM customers 
GROUP BY identify;
```

While running the procedure I get the following error message:

```
The used table type doesn't support BLOB/TEXT columns
```

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468080/mysql-the-used-table-type-does-not-support-blob-text-columns) thread but it didn't help me.

The types on the columns are the following:

```
lastName -> VARCHAR(255)
firstName -> VARCHAR(255)
zip -> VARCHAR(10)
```

when I exclude the zip from the procedure it works as It should so I guess there is a problem with the length of the varchar?

Does anyone knew a solution without changing the varchar length of zip from 10 to 255?

Comment: Can't you just `CAST()` the calculated values back to `VARCHAR()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incidence is presented by the value of the constant `CONVERT_IF_BIGGER_TO_BLOB`:

```cc
/**
  CHAR and VARCHAR fields longer than this number of characters are converted
  to BLOB.
  Non-character fields longer than this number of bytes are converted to BLOB.
  Comparisons should be '>' or '<='.
*/
#define CONVERT_IF_BIGGER_TO_BLOB 512   /* Used for CREATE ... SELECT */
```

[mysql-server/sql/sql_const.h::52](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/71f48ab393bce80a59e5a2e498cd1f46f6b43f9a/sql/sql_const.h#L52)

and

> [16.3 The MEMORY Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html)
>
> - ...
> - Support for variable-length data types (including BLOB and TEXT) not supported by MEMORY.

Example:

```sql
mysql> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp` ENGINE=MEMORY
    -> SELECT SPACE(512) `tmp_col`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp` ENGINE=MEMORY
    -> SELECT SPACE(513) `tmp_col`;
ERROR 1163 (42000): The used table type doesn't support BLOB/TEXT columns
```

Try:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp`, `customers`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `lastName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `firstName` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ->   `zip` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `identify` VARCHAR(520) NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=MEMORY;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `tmp`
    -> SELECT `id`, CONCAT(TRIM(`lastName`),
    ->                     TRIM(`firstName`),
    ->                     TRIM(`zip`)) `identify`
    -> FROM `customers`
    -> GROUP BY `id`, `identify`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Thank your very much for your research and solution!

Answer (score 2):

My experience with ENGINE=MEMORY was that the charset is also relevant.
varchar(65000) with charset latin1 worked; charset UTF8 did not
ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: Thank your very much